# How customize chooser views and add a specific widget to a field using wagtail-generic-chooser

Tags: django, wagtail, wagtail-snippet

I want to override the basic view in the Article snippet selector, which does not display the checkbox correctly.

```
class ArticleChooserMixin(ModelChooserMixin):
    def get_edit_item_url(self, item):
        # for Wagtail 4.x
        return reverse(
            "wagtailsnippets_app_name_article:edit", args=(quote(item.pk),)
        )


class ArticleChooserViewSet(ModelChooserViewSet):
    icon = "user"
    model = Article
    page_title = _("Choose a article")
    per_page = 10
    order_by = "title"
    fields = ["title", "body", "url", "categories", "countries"]

    chooser_mixin_class = ArticleChooserMixin
```

piece of code from the Article model

```
from dal import autocomplete
...

@register_snippet
class Article(
    DraftStateMixin,
    RevisionMixin,
    index.Indexed,
    ClusterableModel,
    Orderable,
    SourceDataMixin,
):
...
categories = ParentalManyToManyField("app_name.ArticleCategory", blank=True)
countries = ParentalManyToManyField("app_name.Country", blank=True)
...
FieldPanel("categories", widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2Multiple())
FieldPanel("countries", widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2Multiple()),
...
```

Similar problem: https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail-generic-chooser/issues/65

View from the snippet creation [how I want it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJyOe.png)  and form elements that display the currently selected item
[current problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STG4z.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the wagtail-generic-chooser docs](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail-generic-chooser#creating-objects-within-the-chooser) - The creation form presented within the chooser is [a plain Django ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/modelforms/), which does not make use of the model's panel definition. If you pass a `fields` attribute on the ViewSet class, it will construct a ModelForm with all of those fields at their default settings. To override this, you can define your own ModelForm class and pass that as `form_class`:

```
from django import forms

class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ["title", "body", "url", "categories", "countries"]
        widgets = {
            "categories": autocomplete.ModelSelect2Multiple(),
            "countries": autocomplete.ModelSelect2Multiple(),
        }


class ArticleChooserViewSet(ModelChooserViewSet):
    # ...
    form_class = ArticleForm
```